# Resize down-scale images only modified today

Tags: batch-file, dos, mogrify

I'm trying to get the following command to work on Server 2003 using an ImageMagik tool called `mogrify`.

> for %G in (.jpg, .png, .gif) do forfiles /p "C:\Images" /s /m *%G -d 0 -c "cmd /c C:\ImageMagick\mogrify.exe -resize 800x800^> -quality 80 -strip @path"

But when the mogrify tool runs for the found path it errors saying the resize arg is invalid.

> mogrify.exe: InvalidArgument `80Ã╬0>': -resize @error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/5754.

I believe the problem relates the value and that it contains `^>`.
The `>` symbol is needed to tell the tool to only downscale either width or height and I think the `^` is needed as an escape character.

Independently the command does work and the image is resized:

> mogrify.exe -resize 800x800^> -quality 80 -strip "image1.jpg"

Also the command works if I remove the resize arg but of course the images are not resized:

> for %G in (.jpg, .png, .gif) do forfiles /p "C:\Images" /s /m *%G -d 0 -c "cmd /c C:\ImageMagick\mogrify.exe -quality 80 -strip @path"

I've also tried variations by wrapping the value with double-quotes and escaping the `^` multiple times but nothing seems to work.

For whats worth I can get the following to work but removing `^` and adding quotes from the resize value.

> cmd /c C:\ImageMagick\mogrify.exe -resize "800x800>" -quality 80 -strip image1.JPG

---

So to summaries how do i correctly add the resize value of `800x800>` to the following command?

> for %G in (.jpg, .png, .gif) do forfiles /p "C:\Images" /s /m *%G -d 0 -c "cmd /c C:\ImageMagick\mogrify.exe -resize 800x800^> -quality 80 -strip @path"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think the problem is that 0x80 is being converted to ASCII from hex.  From the `forfiles /?` help message:

> To include special characters in the command line, use the hexadecimal code for the character in 0xHH format (ex. 0x09 for tab). Internal CMD.exe commands should be preceded with "cmd /c".

Try capitalizing the X in `-resize 800X800^>`.

Comment: For me this didn't work; I had to quote the `^>` part as well: `0x5e0x3e`.